# jQuery Mobile taphold event fires browser dialog

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-plugins

I'm having a problem with taphold event.

I bind taphold event to an image. When I taphold the image on the fly,  android web browser fires a dialog that contains  "save as image", "set as wallpaper","share image" commands.

I want to disable image process command dialog when using taphold event.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found out you have to disable right-clicking.

```
$(function(){

    document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};

    $(document).mousedown(function(e){

        if ( e.button == 2 )
        { 
            alert('Right mouse button!'); 
            return false; 
        }

        return true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call e.preventDefault() to prevent the dialog from poping out.

```
$page.bind("pageinit", function () {
    $("a").bind("taphold", function (e) {
        // your code
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Edit:

What about binding to img instead?

```
$page.bind("pageinit", function () {
    $("img").bind("taphold", function (e) {
        // your code
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no "anchor" on my page :(

Comment: Binding to something other than the anchor doesn't seem to work from what I've researched.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. I was cleared the same problem by the following code

```
     window.oncontextmenu = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
      };
```